# Linq to join two lists and filter using a value of inner list value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a client list, it internally contains list of phone numbers, i need to filter the list of client which matches the client phone number from another list of phonenumbers using linq.

Here is my code

My client object is

```
public class Client
{
   public int id;
   public string firstname;
   public string lastname;
   public List<phone> phones;
    //etc.
}

public class phone
{
    public int id;
    public string phoneno;
}

var searchByPhone = new List<string,string>();

searchByPhone.Add("12324344", "message one");
searchByPhone.Add("45646565", "message two");
searchByPhone.Add("56868675", "message three");

//first one is phone number and second is the text message.
```

Here my need is

I need to list the clients by searchByPhone phonenumber from client phones list and merge the result set to new Clientobject mentioned below. any help please?

```
public class ClientObject
{
    public int id;
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
    public string phonenumber;
    public string message; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var searchByPhone = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
searchByPhone.Add(Tuple.Create("12324344", "message one"));
searchByPhone.Add(Tuple.Create("45646565", "message two"));
searchByPhone.Add(Tuple.Create("56868675", "message three"));

//you should already have this list populated somehow, i'm declaring it here just for the sake of making the code compile
var clientlist = new List<Client>();

//this list will hold your results
List<ClientObject> resultList = new List<ClientObject>();


searchByPhone.ForEach(tp => resultList.AddRange(
                clientlist.Where(cl => cl.phones.Any(ph=>ph.phoneno == tp.Item1)).Select(cl => new ClientObject {id = cl.id, firstname = cl.firstname, lastname = cl.lastname, message = tp.Item2, phonenumber = tp.Item1}).ToList()));
```

Note: you either need to make the members of client, clientobject and phone classes public, or preferably create public properties to get/set their values.

This will give you a list of ClientObject objects, which contain the id, first and last name from the Client object as well as the appropraite number and message from the searchByPhone tuples.
I think that is what you were after. If not, please clarify your needs and I can adjust the answer

Comment: You can't have a List<string,string>
It's either a list of objects or some other data container. Like Dictionary<string,string> perhaps?

Check your code again, List<string,string> wouldn't compile. (Assuming System.Collections.Generic.List)

Comment: thanks i made it as list of object with phone and textmessage

Comment: Then it should work just the same. You do a .ForEach on that list, and where it says tp.Item1  and tp.Item2  replace it with  tp.<name of field you use for the number> and tp.<name of field you use for the message>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var data = (from dt in searchByPhone
                    let cl = clientList.Where(z => z.phones.Any(y => y.phoneno.Equals(dt.Item1)))
                    select cl.Select(x => new ClientObject
                                              {
                                                  firstname = x.firstname,
                                                  lastname = x.lastname,
                                                  id = x.id,
                                                  phonenumber = dt.Item1,
                                                  message = dt.Item2
                                              })).Aggregate((a, b) =>
                                              {
                                                  a.ToList().AddRange(b);
                                                  return a;
                                              });
```

Comment: Note that if there are multiple clients using a same phone number, this code will only take into account the first client it finds.

That doesn't sound too logical, but is something to be aware of. My implementation will include all clients with a given phone number.

Comment: Updated for new context.